# Find all the links on a webpage and download automatically all of them as separeted html files using php

Tags: php, html, curl

sorry for my english I would try to explain better as possible and I hope somebody can help me... thanks in advace.

I'm trying to make a page in PHP that read the webpage source of a given URL,,, find all the links and then for each single link (if is a html) download automatically the file on my pc (better without asking where...).

Until now I try this code:

```
 <?php

    $srcUrl= 'www.example.com';

    $html = file_get_contents($srcUrl);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    // grab all the on the page
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    //finding the a tag
    $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

    $testo = '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" summary="layout">
      <caption>
        List of links
      </caption>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>';

    //Loop to display all the links and download
    for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {

           $href = $hrefs->item($i);
           $url = $href->getAttribute('href');

     //if real link
           if($url!='#')  

           {

        $testo.='<tr>
        <td>'.$url.'</td>
        </tr>';
     //take webpage
     $contents = file_get_contents($url);

     $filename = $url;

     //save the file...
     $fh = fopen($filename,"w");
     fwrite($fh,$contents);
     fclose($fh);

    //download automatically (better if without asking where... maybe in download folder)
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-type: text/html');

           }

    }

    $testo.='</table>';

    echo $testo;

    ?>
```

And I even try with curl:

```
<?php

$srcUrl= 'www.example.com';

$html = file_get_contents($srcUrl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//finding the a tag
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

$testo = '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" summary="layout">
  <caption>
    List of links
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>';

//Loop to display all the links and download
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {

       $href = $hrefs->item($i);
       $url = $href->getAttribute('href');

 //if real link
       if($url!='#')  

       {

    $testo.='<tr>
    <td>'.$url.'</td>
    </tr>';
 //take webpage
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

 $filename = $url;

 $filename = $url;

 //save the file...
 $fh = fopen($filename,"w");
 fwrite($fh,$contents);
 fclose($fh);

//download automatically (better if without asking where... maybe in download folder)
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-type: text/html');

       }

}

$testo.='</table>';

echo $testo;

?>
```

but don't work!

Comment: As I'm not too familiar with php, but have had similar frustrations with downloading links from a site, I'll comment what I think might be wrong:

most of the times the links are stored as /some_dir/some_page rather than with the http://example.com

if I'm not mistaken, you don't take that into account and it would of course lead to errors. 

Also, you might want to specify exactly what's not working (error message/outputs) for people to be able to give more insightful help.

Comment: The two examples look the same. I see no curl example.

Comment: Your script makes no sense. The header would force a download of a file that is saved on the server and you want the table to be displayed? That's sort of a logic issue and your work flow needs to be addressed first. What are you expecting to have the script do?

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for the comment, The logic is to show a list of the links in a webpage to the user on screen while the script download each single page on server. Anyway I understand where the problem is.